# Deploy a war file inside the embedded servlet container in a Spring Boot web application

Tags: spring-boot, servlet-container

I want to deploy one or more already existing war files into the embedded servlet container in the Spring Boot project.

Specifically, I want to fire up both the hawtio and the ActiveMQ Web Console wars inside the same application, in addition to some of my own stuff.

Is there a correct way to do this, or do I have to go for the "nuclear option" of configuring the servlet container instance myself? (Note that I'd rather have Jetty than Tomcat, but if it is one line with Tomcat, and lots of cruft with Jetty, then Tomcat is okay)

Comment: please check this question, and if you will be satisfied with the answer flag this question as a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24634166/deploying-a-third-party-war-in-a-spring-boot-embedded-container?rq=1

Comment: @ShadyRagab: Very similar problem. And also this, it turns out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916935/spring-boot-embedded-wars
But the answer was not satisfactory.